# Reactive @PreAuthroize on service not evaluated in test

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I want to test that access is denied by a service, but the `@PreAuthorize` is not evaluated. I am probably missing some configuration, but I cannot figure out what.

This is the service

```kotlin
@Service
class FooServiceImpl : FooService {
  @PreAuthorize("denyAll")
  suspend fun bar() {
    println("I am not accessible")
  }
}
```

This is the test where I would expect an `AccessDeniedException`:

```kotlin
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
@Import(TestSecurityConfig::class)
internal class FooServiceImplTest {
  @InjectMockKs
  lateinit var fooService: FooServiceImpl
  @Test
  fun shouldDeny() {
    runBlocking {
      assertThrows<Exception> {
        fooService.bar()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is my imported test config:

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
class TestSecurityConfig {
  @Bean
  fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain? {
    return http {
      csrf { disable() }
      formLogin { disable() }
      httpBasic { disable() }
      authorizeExchange {
        authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The test fails:

```
Expected java.lang.Exception to be thrown, but nothing was thrown.
```

I also tried adding `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)` (but as far as I understood this is not required when using `@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity`?) and also tried adding the annotations directly on the test class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to think about how the service under test is created. In the setup of the question the `@InjectMockks` of course creates the instance directly instead of in a spring contest. Without the context, no security is interwoven.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class, MockKExtension::class)
@Import(TestSecurityConfig::class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = [FooServiceImpl::class])
internal class FooServiceImplTest {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var fooService: FooService
  // ...
}
```

Note 1: The `FooServiceImpl` now is selected via the `@ContextConfiguration` and then `@Autowired` to `fooService` by refering to it's interface.

Note 2: Previously I was using `@MockK` for dependencies (not shown in the question) of the `FooService`. They now must be `@MockKBean`s.